# How to add tags on TrainnigJob cloudwatch log stream in sagemaker notebooks?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sagemaker

I use a AWS Sagemaker notebook to train a TensorFlow ML model unsing my own entrypoint script.
I need to tag my training with some information which I'm currently doing like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from sagemaker import get_execution_role

sagemaker_session = sagemaker.Session()
region = sagemaker_session.boto_session.region_name

from sagemaker.tensorflow import TensorFlow


tags = [{'Key': 'Project',
         'Value': 'my-project-1'
        }]

tf_estimator = TensorFlow(entry_point='train_mlp.py',
                          output_path='s3://path/to/my/output',
                          model_name='mlp',
                          role=get_execution_role(),
                          instance_count=1,
                          instance_type='ml.c5.4xlarge',
                          framework_version=tf.__version__,
                          py_version='py310',
                          script_mode=True,
                          base_job_name='my-training-1',
                          tags=tags,
                          disable_profiler=True,
                          hyperparameters={
                              'epochs': 1
                          }
                         )

tf_estimator.fit()
```

When the training starts, I can go into the cloudwatch UI and see my logs for `my-training-1-<timestamp>`.
Now my qustion is, how can I add tags to this Log Steam directly from the notbook instance, without going into the cloudwatch UI if I need to add some tags similar to the tags for the training job?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

CloudWatch log streams [cannot be tagged](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_TagResource.html):

> Currently, the only CloudWatch Logs resources that can be tagged are log groups and destinations.

Because all training job log streams are added to the `/aws/sagemaker/TrainingJobs` log group, you probably won't get much benefit from adding tags to it.

Comment: Thanks for that hint. And how could I tag a log group?

Comment: `import boto3`

`client = boto3.client('logs')`

`client.tag_log_group(
    logGroupName='string',
    tags={
        'string': 'string'
    }
)`